# Remove "Build Workspace" keyboard shortcut from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

I'm encountering a sometimes annoying, sometimes maddening issue with Eclipse (Juno, OS X Mountain Lion). It seems that CMD + B is mapped to the "Build Workspace" trigger in Eclipse. I don't build any of my source from within Eclipse and yet this action invariably blocks all other interaction. Worse yet, it often freezes in the "build" process, in which case I have to forcibly kill the process. Since "B" is adjacent to "V", and CMD + V is paste, this happens somewhat regularly. And the "Build Workspace" shortcut seems to be missing from the General -> Keys menu.

Any idea how I can disable this keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5):

Have used Eclipse on Mac/Linux/Windows and found the key bindings to be pretty similar across platforms. Happen to be on Windows at the moment, so maybe this picture:
[image: link] will help? Am hoping that you are looking specifically for "Build Workspace" when what you want to look for is "Build All".

Comment: The "Build All" is listed as having no binding in that menu, however the key combination still triggers a build.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know. How about configuring the Java Build Path for the project to include no sources? Would that work for you or do you want to be able to navigate through the code (Open Declaration, etc.)? At that point, you might as well just use something like TextMate 2. Another idea is to try using a different eclipse _perspective_ that either doesn't bind CTRL-B at all or binds it to something less annoying.